# JavaScript buttons returning wrong alert

Tags: javascript, for-loop, button

I'm applying for a job and they threw a JS question detailed below:

*Write a function to render 10 `<button>` elements on the page, numbered 1 through 10, and alert the number of the chosen button when one is clicked. Do **not** use jQuery or any other libraries.*

Seems easy enough. I've built a working model except for it alerts the wrong number. It alerts Button 11 for all the buttons. I know I'm forgetting something simple. Below is my code (feel free to critique it if you have a better way of organizing this). Also here is a link to a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/alexmarple/5j994rm3/) that works save for the alert.

```
var count = 1;

function createBtn(){
  var button = document.createElement("button");
  button.innerHTML = "Button " + count;
  var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
  body.appendChild(button);
  button.addEventListener ("click", function() {
    alert('Button ' + count);
  });
}

function buttonRender(){
  for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    createBtn();
    count++;
  }
}

buttonRender();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should pass count to the function.

```
function createBtn(count){
  var button = document.createElement("button");
  button.innerHTML = "Button " + count;
  var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
  body.appendChild(button);
  button.addEventListener ("click", function() {
    alert('Button ' + count);
  });
}

function buttonRender(){
  for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    createBtn(count);
    count++;
  }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xw7mhag2/

Comment: Ah! I knew it was something simple. I will make this the answer in 10 minutes when Stack Overflow lets me. Thanks Alberto!

Comment: This answer would be so much more awesome if it explained _why_ count is 11 for all the buttons, even if it has the right value at the time the buttons are created...

Answer (score 0):

```
var count = 0;

  function createBtn(count){
    var button = document.createElement("button");
    button.innerHTML = "Button " + count;
    var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
    body.appendChild(button);
    button.addEventListener ("click", function() {
      alert("Button " + count);
    });
  }

  function buttonRender(){
    for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    count++;
      createBtn(count);

    }
  }

  buttonRender();
```